# page flipping effect

Tags: animations

There are commercial software that create the look of an analog page flipping effect from a PDF document. Is there a similar animation in TeX? (Not to be confused with flippdf package which gives a mirror image for printing machines.)

Comment: I am sorry, but I feel so very strongly against this kind of useless distracting effects, so -1. If I could rid the world of this effect, I would, to make the world a better place.

Comment: @morbusg As someone who was comfortable with simplicity of _troff_ I appreciate your point of view. These pages are filled with ways of how to provide sharp digital presentations in professional gatherings. However, in the field of education,  analog looks and soft feels are time-honored ways to teach. I am trying to find those analog looks, in a digital world, that hopefully improve the educational experience and make the world a better place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/): It's a presentation software written in Python and running on Windows, Linux and Macintosh. Amongst other transition effects, it supports two page flipping effects, `PagePeel` and `PageTurn`. The transitions can be configured in a text file.

#### Example

If you have a presentation `mytalk.pdf`, create a text file called `mytalk.pdf.info`. In order to use e. g. the `PageTurn` effect between slide 1 and 2 and to use no transitions in the rest of the presentation, the contents of this file would look like this:

```
DocumentTitle = "My talk"
PageProps = {
  1: {
       'transition': PageTurn
     }
}
AvailableTransitions = [None]
```

More information on how to configure the appearance of your presentations can be found in [the Impressive manual](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/manual.php).